# How do I pivot a data frame wider turning a variable of numbers (e.g. election years) into dichotomous variables

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot

I have a data frame of election survey data. One variable lists the year of the election, other variables report individual level data (e.g. vote choice, gender).

How do I turn the variable that contains the election year (in this case var1) into a series of dichotomous variables.
I can do this with a series of Recodes, but I'd like to make pivot_wider work here.

```
var1<-sample(seq(1,5, 1), size=500, replace=T)
var2<-sample(c("red", "orange"), size=500, replace=T)
var3<-sample(c(0,1), size=500, replace=T)
df<-data.frame(var1, var2, var3)
library(tidyverse)
df
df %>% 
  pivot_wider(., names_from=var1, values_from=var1)
```

Comment: What is the output supposed to look like? Is there one column for each `var1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%  
  pivot_wider(id_cols = var1:var3, 
            names_from = var1, 
            values_from = var1, 
            values_fn = \(x) as.integer(length(x) > 0),
            values_fill = 0L,
            names_sort = T)
```

```
  var2    var3   `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`
  <chr>  <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 red        1     1     1     1     1     1
2 red        0     1     1     1     1     1
3 orange     1     1     1     1     1     1
4 orange     0     1     1     1     1     1
```

or summing:

```
df %>%  
  pivot_wider(id_cols = var1:var3, 
            names_from = var1, 
            values_from = var1, 
            values_fn = \(x) as.integer(sum(x)),
            values_fill = 0L,
            names_sort = T)
```

```
var2    var3   `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`
  <chr>  <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 red        1    27    56    54    84   165
2 red        0    20    50    90   128   115
3 orange     1    17    56    54    72   100
4 orange     0    27    70    78   108   135
```